# Pivoted Rod Problem

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, equilibrium

[image]

Hi this question popped up on AP Physics C practice test, and I keep on getting T = mg/2 through equilibrium. I got the torque from gravity is mgsinthetaR/2 and the torque from the Wire is TsinthetaR, and since the rod is at equilibrium, T = mg/2. However, this is not the correct answer. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Torque from gravity is incorrect.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you neglected the angle, the correct answer should be $\frac {mg}{2\tan \theta}$.

It would be better to follow the steps when considering questions.

1. draw all the forces
2. write down the equation ( equibrilium and moment equibrilium)
3. solve them.

Comment: Please don't answer "do my homework for me" type questions. This isn't a homework help site and answering them only encourages more of these types of questions that we don't want.